# Toggle button is in off state though the value of it is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a switch in one of the many tabs such as Help, About etc. as shown below:

[image]

As you can see, the value of it is set programmatically based on a state variable in componentDidMount(). But the toggle button doesn't reflect the value accordingly. I want it to always change accordingly when the component is mounted.

Comment: I don't know how your toggle button is setup but checkbox inputs use the `checked` attribute to indicate if they are on or off. Try changing whatever code is setting `value` to adding or removing `checked`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Previously I was doing:

```
componentDidMount() {
const {solar} = this.props;
document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleGlobalKeyDown );
var toggleButton = document.getElementsByName("toggle")[0];
toggleButton.value = solar;
}
```

I changed it to:

```
componentDidMount() {
const {solar} = this.props;
document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleGlobalKeyDown );
this.state.checked = solar;
}
```

And it worked!